# Laravel - Vue Multiple Page Application with Single Vue Instance

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, multi-page-application

I am using Laravel for a project and would like to switch Vue. This is a sample of my setup right now:-

"routes/web.php"

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@home');
Route::get('/about', 'HomeController@about');
Route::get('/blogs', 'HomeController@blogs');
```

"views/master.blade.php"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <!-- AND OTHER STUFF -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- NAV BAR -->


    <div id="app">
      @yield('content')
    </div>


    <script src="app.build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

"views/pages/home.blade.php"

```
@extends('master')

@section('title', "Home")

@section('content')
  <home-content
    customproperties="{{ $somedata }}"
  ></home-content>
@endsection
```

"app.js"

```
var vm = new Vue({
    data(){
        return {

        }
    },
    components: {
        HomeContent,
        AboutContent,
        BlogsContent
    }
})
```

Let's suppose I have all the components ready and working just fine. The problem is, am I doing it the right way? I don't want to make it a single page application for project complexity, instead I want to do it hybrid way. All vue components will have their respective pages, and some pages will not even have a vue component, just a Plain Blade page.

For example, a static page may look like this:-

```
@extends('master')

@section('title', "Static Page")

@section('content')
  Just a static page, it has nothing to do with vue, but still sitting inside Vue instance's template scope.
@endsection
```

For these pages, the vue script is being loaded and "#app" is getting interpreted as a template. But this page will have no use for vue. Is it good to leave it this way? Or a more optimal way exists for this?

Any suggestions regarding best practices for Laravel-Vue multi page application is welcome.

Comment: I don't think there is a definitive answer to this question. It depends on how complex the project is. One downside of the approach you mentioned is that you'll have to load components which are used on only a single page on all pages. It the number of "major" components (Home, About, and Blog in your example) is small, maybe you could break it up into a few different scripts (i.e. each script having a Vue instance with only that component loaded), and include the appropriate script in your HTML?

Comment: Thanks, It crossed my mind too. I was just unsure whether I am doing it right or not. Was looking for some expert opinion.

Comment: @Amade, can't you use dynamic  aysnc loading feature of VueJS instead of loading all components at a time as described here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components ?

Comment: Did you find any solution?